# Celery task handlers vs signals

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

Celery tasks have [on_success handler](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#on_success) and [task-success signal](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#task-success).
what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#abstract-classes):

> Abstract classes are not registered, but are used as the base class
>   for new task types.

So apparently handlers are methods that you can override to do something. You can see example of custom handler `after_return` in the docs actually:

```
from celery import Task

class DebugTask(Task):
    abstract = True

    def after_return(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Task returned: {0!r}'.format(self.request)
```

Signals are means of decoupling, so you can make your code listening from outside for some event to happen and act appropriately.